# subclassing TTTableMessageItemCell, anything wrong?

Tags: three20

I subclassing TTTableMessageItemCell, got EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime error. Anythign wrong?

CustomTTTableSubtitleItemCell.h

```
#import "Three20/Three20.h"
@interface CustomTTTableSubtitleItemCell : TTTableMessageItemCell {
    TTButton *_rightButton;
}

@end
```

CustomTTTableSubtitleItemCell.m

```
#import "CustomTTTableSubtitleItemCell.h"
#import "CustomTTTableSubtitleItem.h"
#import "XYDefaultStyleSheet.h"
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static CGFloat kHPadding = 10;
static CGFloat kVPadding = 15;


@interface ButtonStyleSheet : TTDefaultStyleSheet
@end

@implementation ButtonStyleSheet

- (TTStyle*)blueToolbarButton:(UIControlState)state {
    TTShape* shape = [TTRoundedRectangleShape shapeWithRadius:4.5];
    UIColor* tintColor = RGBCOLOR(30, 110, 255);
    return [TTSTYLESHEET toolbarButtonForState:state shape:shape tintColor:tintColor font:nil];
}

@end


@implementation CustomTTTableSubtitleItemCell


+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView rowHeightForItem:(id)item {
    CustomTTTableSubtitleItem* captionedItem = item;

    CGFloat maxWidth = tableView.width - kHPadding*2;

    CGSize titleSize = [captionedItem.title sizeWithFont:TTSTYLEVAR(myTitleFont)
                                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGSize textSize = [captionedItem.text sizeWithFont:TTSTYLEVAR(myHeadingFont)
                                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize subtextSize = [captionedItem.caption sizeWithFont:TTSTYLEVAR(mySubtextFont)
                                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return kVPadding*2 + titleSize.height + textSize.height + subtextSize.height + kVPadding;
}




- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:identifier]) {
        _item = nil;
        [TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:[[[ButtonStyleSheet alloc] init] autorelease]];


    }
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self.detailTextLabel sizeToFit];
    self.detailTextLabel.top = kVPadding;

    self.textLabel.height = self.detailTextLabel.height;

    //_rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.detailTextLabel.bottom + kVPadding, kImageWidth, kImageHeight);

        //_rightButton.alpha = !self.showingDeleteConfirmation;
        [_rightButton sizeToFit];
        _rightButton.left = self.contentView.width - (_timestampLabel.width + kHPadding);
        _rightButton.top = self.height/2;



}

- (id)object {
    return _item;
}

- (void)setObject:(id)object {
    if (_item != object) {
        [super setObject:object];

        CustomTTTableSubtitleItem* item = object;


        //self.textLabel.textColor = TTSTYLEVAR(myHeadingColor);
//      self.textLabel.font = TTSTYLEVAR(myHeadingFont);
//      self.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
//      self.textLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
//      self.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
//      self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
//      
//      self.detailTextLabel.textColor = TTSTYLEVAR(mySubtextColor);
//      self.detailTextLabel.font = TTSTYLEVAR(mySubtextFont);
//      self.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
//      self.detailTextLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
//      self.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;


        _rightButton = [TTButton 
                        buttonWithStyle:@"blueToolbarButton:" title:item.rightButtonTitle]; 




    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(_rightButton);
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the TTButton using autorelease, while you're releasing it in your dealloc function. So both the release pool and the dealloc are trying to release your _rightButton TTButton.

in your header file, try adding:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) TTButton*      rightButton;
```

And then create the TTButton using his get function in your source file:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (TTButton*)rightButton {
 if (!_rightButton) {
    _rightButton = [[TTButton 
                     buttonWithStyle:@"blueToolbarButton:" title:item.rightButtonTitle] retain]; 

    [self.contentView addSubview:rightButton];
  }
 return rightButton;
}
```

When using the rightButton, make sure to use self.rightBotton and not _rightButton, such as in the layout function (Because you need to object to be created).

```
self.rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.detailTextLabel.bottom + kVPadding, kImageWidth, kImageHeight);
```

I suggest opening the Three20UI/TTTableMessageItemCell.h & source file and trying to copy the behavior of one of the elements. That's what I did.